# The value of finite sum involving factorials

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have been facing difficulties of solving this finite sum stated below. I know it will be $e^x$ if the summation goes to infinity. how can i deal with if its finite sum. any hint will be highly appreciated

$$\sum_{n=0}^k \frac{x^n}{n!}$$

Comment: I don't understand your question: it is a polynomial, usually polynomial functions are described by themselves. For example, for $k=1$, it's the polynomial $x+1$: what else should it be?

Answer (score 1):

Using Taylor-Lagrange formula, with the function $x\mapsto e^x$, at the interval $[0,x] $, we find that

$$\sum_{k=0}^n\frac {x^k}{k!}=e^x-\frac {x^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}e^c $$
for some $c\in (0,x) $.

Comment: You should say that you use the version of Taylor theorem with Lagrange's remainder (https://gowers.wordpress.com/2014/02/11/taylors-theorem-with-the-lagrange-form-of-the-remainder/).

Answer (score 0):

It equals to
$$
e^x-\int_{0}^{x}\frac{t^{k+1}}{\left(k+1\right)!}e^t\text{d}t
$$